# javaScript check for at least one alphanumeric character in string

Tags: javascript, alphanumeric

In my application someone can submit text from another language. I'd like for only English alphanumeric strings to be entered. I've got this JavaScript function working but wondering if this is the best method for doing this?

```
var string = $('input[name=title]').val();
if((/\d/.test(string) || /[a-zA-Z]/.test(string)) === false) {
    alert('Field has no Alphanumeric characters.');
    fPass = false;
}
```

Even if some just enters 1 character I want that to be allowed, as long as it is a number or a character from one of the 26 letters in the English alphabet (case insensitive)

Without using a function here is what I've come up with

```
if((/[\da-z]/i.test(string)) === false) {
    alert('Please use alphanumeric characters.')
}
```

Comment: `/[\da-z]/i`...

Comment: @zerkms what about the === false part?

Comment: You need to check whether it returned `true` or `false` indeed.

Comment: would it make a difference if it where == or === ?

Comment: In this case - no, but in general I personally never used `==` in at least last 5 years

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your regex into one expression.

```
function hasAlphanumeric(str) {
  return /\d|[A-z]/.test(str)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^[\da-z]+$
```

[image]

---

```js
let allowAlphanumeric = (str) =>{
  return /^[\da-z]+$/i.test(str)
}

console.log(allowAlphanumeric('$#@'))
console.log(allowAlphanumeric(''))
console.log(allowAlphanumeric('  '))
console.log(allowAlphanumeric('abchbchdb12e44'))
```

Comment: @zerkms there's `i` flag which will take care of case insensitivity mate

Comment: Yep, and you added it AFTER I posted a comment. Still, it's not what OP asked. They asked not about _all_, but _any_ character.

Comment: @zerkms `I'd like for only English alphanumeric strings to be entered.`  this is what written in question

Comment: "Even if some just enters 1 character I want that to be allowed", it really makes sense to read through the end of the question :shrug: